# General guideline for setting appropriate font size for a document

Tags: fonts

I print out my cv made in LaTeX today. After printing it seems to me that the font size is very small. I didn't use any specific font for the cv, I use package `fullpage`.

So, I open this question if experts would make some answer or discussion about choosing appropriate font size for a document. Beginners suffer many on choosing best font size in LaTeX.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fullpage}

%\usepackage{doublespace}
%\setstretch{1.2}

\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{CV}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
      linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

%Ueberschrift
\begin{center}
\huge{\textsc{Curriculum Vitae}}
\vspace{\baselineskip}

\Large{\textsc{MD.Al-Helal}}\\
\end{center}
\vspace{1.5\baselineskip}

\section{Address}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{.7\textwidth}
  Room no-1406\\
  Shahid Sarafat Ali Building\\
  Dr. Muhammad Shahidullah Hall\\
  University of Dhaka\\
  Dhaka-1000\\
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.7\textwidth}
  \faPhone{} +8801515-611989\\
  \faEnvelopeO{}  \href{mailto:al2helal@gmail.com}{al2helal@gmail.com}\\
  \faEnvelopeO{}  \href{mailto:alhelal@ieee.org}{alhelal@ieee.org}\\
  \faGithub{}  \href{https://github.com/al2helal}{al2helal}\\
  \faLinkedin{}  \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/mdalhelal/}{al2helal}\\
  \faStackOverflow{}  \href{https://stackoverflow.com/users/5697418/alhelal}{alhelal}
\end{minipage}

\section{Personal Details}
\begin{CV}
  \item[Gender] Male 
  \item[Father] Md.Akbar Ali
  \item[Mother] Most. Bilkis Begum
  \item[Date of birth] 2nd June, 1996
  \item[Permanent Address] Vill. Moyenpur, P.O. Kashimpur Hajigong-5460, Upa. Mithapukur, Dist. Rangpur
  \item[Nationality] Bangladeshi
  \item[Religion] Islam
  \end{CV}

\section{Career Objective}
\begin{CV}
\item To build up an efficient carrer in the computer science and engineering and thereby serve humanity.
  \end{CV}

\section{Working Experience}

\begin{CV}

\item[2018] Completed a project on making a e-commerce site(an online handicraft's store).
\item[2017] Completed a project on making a suggestion provider text editor with IDE features.
\item[2017] Completed a project on building a statistical predictive and recommendation model on universtity student's salary as tutor.
\end{CV}


\section{Education}

\begin{CV}
\item[2015--current] University of Dhaka, Dhaka-1000.\\Continued  B.S in Computer Science \& Engineering. Currently in 4\textsuperscript{th} year.\\Obtained CGPA 3.33 (upto 3rd year)
\item[2014] Carmichael College, Rangpur.\\Passed H.S.C (Science Group) under Dinajpur Board in 2014.\\Obtained GPA 5.00 (without 4\textsuperscript{th} subject score) out of 5.00.
\item[2012] Moyenpur High School, Mithapukur, Rangpur.\\Passed S.S.C (Science Group) under Dinajpur Board in 2012.\\Obtained GPA 5.00 (without 4\textsuperscript{th} subject score) out of 5.00.
\end{CV}


%\section{Language Skills}
%\begin{table}[h] %\centering
%\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}>{}p{2.5cm}p{3cm}}
%Bangali  & native \\
%English  & 2nd language\\
%\end{tabular}
%\end{table}


%\section{Areas of Interest}
%\begin{CV}
%\item Machine learning, System programming, Making helpful shell script.
%\end{CV}


\section{Scholarship}

\begin{CV}
\item[2009] Obtained National Education Board Scholarship for good result in class 8.
\item[2014] Obtained National Education Board Scholarship for good result in H.S.C under Dinajpur Board.
\end{CV}

%\section{Technical Skills}
%\begin{table}[h]
%  \begin{tabular}{p{5cm}>{}p{6cm}}
%    Programming Languages  & C, Java, Sql, Mysql, HTML, R, Assembly\\
%    Tools & Oracle database, PhpMyadmin\\
%Version Control  & Git\\
%IDE & IntelliJ, Netbeans, Code Blocks\\
%Text Editor & Vim\\
%Operating System & Ubuntu, Fedora, Windows\\
%Typesetting & \LaTeX{}, Open office, Microsoft office\\
%\end{tabular}
%\end{table}

\section{Technical Skills}

\begin{CV}
\item[Languages]  C, Java, Python, Sql, Mysql, HTML, R, Assembly
\item[Tools] Oracle database, PhpMyadmin
\item[VCS] Git
\item[IDE] IntelliJ, Netbeans, Code Blocks
\item[Text Editor] Vim, VSCode
\item[OS] Ubuntu, Fedora, Kali Linux, Windows
\item[Typesetting] \LaTeX{}, Open office, Microsoft office
\end{CV}
\section{References}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
  \textbf{Dr. Md. Mustafizur Rahman}\\
  Professor \& Chairperson\\
Computer Science \& Engineering\\
University of Dhaka\\
\faPhone{} +8801927199301(Cell)\\
\faPhone (880)-2-9661900 Ext. 7433 (Office)\\
\faEnvelopeO{} \href{mailto:mustafiz@du.ac.bd}{mustafiz@du.ac.bd}\\
\faEnvelopeO{} \href{mailto:mustafiz1952@gmail.com}{mustafiz1952@gmail.com}\\
\faEnvelopeO{} \href{mailto:mustafiz1952@yahoo.com}{mustafiz1952@yahoo.com}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\noindent \today



\end{document}

%Tabellen
\begin{table}[htbp] \centering%
\begin{tabular}{lll}\hline\hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
1 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Titel\label{Tabelle: Label}}
\end{table}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think the question is too broad and you have to add a MWE (your CV with changed anything you want to hide... or to show different, as in more CVs :P )... I am commenting this way because `fullpage` is something that has to be used is some cases but makes things worse in others and probably in your case...

Comment: @koleygr I added my tex file of CV

Comment: The default font size is 10 pt. If you think it's too small, try 11 pt. Note the `ae` has been obsolete for quite a few years, and you may remove it.

Comment: Tested and I think the first command has to be `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}`... I added this comment because of the possibility that the op doesn't know how to change the font size in the whole document (and thus did this question).

Comment: note you are using the wrong syntax for size changed `huge{\textsc{Curriculum Vitae}}`  would make _all_ the following text huge not the text in `{...}` the scope of the size change is the end of the current group or the end of the document. Also why `ae` package? It is surprising to see that used these days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good font size depends on the text width. Experiments have shown that the number of characters in a line of single column text on a page should be in the range of 60 to 70 for ease of reading. For double column text the ideal number of characters in each column is around 45 plus or minus 5. If lines are too long it is hard to pick up the start of the next line while if too short then the eye is constantly flicking back and forth.

For further details about this see my *A Few Notes on Book Design* (`> texdoc memdesign`) Chapter 3 **The Page** and in particular Section 3.3 **The typeblock**.