# How to add round picture in CV using CV package?

Tags: cv, includegraphics

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fullpage}

%\usepackage{doublespace}
%\setstretch{1.2}

\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{CV}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
      linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

%Ueberschrift
\begin{center}
\huge{\textsc{Curriculum Vitae}}
\vspace{\baselineskip}

\Large{\textsc{MD.Al-Helal}}\\
\end{center}
\vspace{1.5\baselineskip}

\section{Address}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{.7\textwidth}
  Room no-1406\\
  Shahid Sarafat Ali Building\\
  Dr. Muhammad Shahidullah Hall\\
  University of Dhaka\\
  Dhaka-1000\\
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.7\textwidth}
  \faPhone{} +8801515-611989\\
  \faEnvelopeO{}  \href{mailto:al2helal@gmail.com}{al2helal@gmail.com}\\
  \faEnvelopeO{}  \href{mailto:alhelal@ieee.org}{alhelal@ieee.org}\\
  \faGithub{}  \href{https://github.com/al2helal}{al2helal}\\
  \faLinkedin{}  \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/mdalhelal/}{al2helal}\\
  \faStackOverflow{}  \href{https://stackoverflow.com/users/5697418/alhelal}{alhelal}
\end{minipage}

\section{Personal Details}
\begin{CV}
  \item[Gender] Male 
  \item[Father] Md.Akbar Ali
  \item[Mother] Most. Bilkis Begum
  \item[Date of birth] 2nd June, 1996
  \item[Permanent Address] Vill. Moyenpur, P.O. Kashimpur Hajigong-5460, Upa. Mithapukur, Dist. Rangpur
  \item[Nationality] Bangladeshi
  \item[Religion] Islam
  \end{CV}

\section{Career Objective}
\begin{CV}
\item To build up an efficient carrer in the computer science and engineering and thereby serve humanity.
  \end{CV}

\section{Working Experience}

\begin{CV}

\item[2016] Completed Database System course and lab. In this course I have learnt database system concept and implemented those in Oracle Database.
\item[2018] Completed a project on making a e-commerce site(an online handicraft's store). I used PHP in back-end(server) and HTML, CSS, JavaScript, AJAX in front-end. I also used MySql in this project to build a MariaDB database.
\item[2017] Completed a project on making a suggestion provider text editor with IDE features. In this editor, user can edit and compile different programming languages's source code. The editor has a intelegence module that can help the user providing stackoverflow suggestion on his/her error of code.
\item[2017] Completed a project on building a statistical predictive and recommendation model on universtity student's salary as tutor. I used R to complete this project.
\end{CV}


\section{Education}

\begin{CV}
\item[2015--current] University of Dhaka, Dhaka-1000.\\Continued  B.S in Computer Science \& Engineering. Currently in 4\textsuperscript{th} year.\\Obtained CGPA 3.33 (upto 3rd year)
\item[2014] Carmichael College, Rangpur.\\Passed H.S.C (Science Group) under Dinajpur Board in 2014.\\Obtained GPA 5.00 (without 4\textsuperscript{th} subject score) out of 5.00.
\item[2012] Moyenpur High School, Mithapukur, Rangpur.\\Passed S.S.C (Science Group) under Dinajpur Board in 2012.\\Obtained GPA 5.00 (without 4\textsuperscript{th} subject score) out of 5.00.
\end{CV}


%\section{Language Skills}
%\begin{table}[h] %\centering
%\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}>{}p{2.5cm}p{3cm}}
%Bangali  & native \\
%English  & 2nd language\\
%\end{tabular}
%\end{table}


%\section{Areas of Interest}
%\begin{CV}
%\item Machine learning, System programming, Making helpful shell script.
%\end{CV}


\section{Scholarship}

\begin{CV}
\item[2009] Obtained National Education Board Scholarship for good result in class 8.
\item[2014] Obtained National Education Board Scholarship for good result in H.S.C under Dinajpur Board.
\end{CV}

%\section{Technical Skills}
%\begin{table}[h]
%  \begin{tabular}{p{5cm}>{}p{6cm}}
%    Programming Languages  & C, Java, Sql, Mysql, HTML, R, Assembly\\
%    Tools & Oracle database, PhpMyadmin\\
%Version Control  & Git\\
%IDE & IntelliJ, Netbeans, Code Blocks\\
%Text Editor & Vim\\
%Operating System & Ubuntu, Fedora, Windows\\
%Typesetting & \LaTeX{}, Open office, Microsoft office\\
%\end{tabular}
%\end{table}

\section{Technical Skills}

\begin{CV}
\item[Languages]  Java, PHP, Python, C, Sql, Mysql, HTML, R, Assembly
\item[Tools] Oracle database, PhpMyadmin
\item[VCS] Git
\item[IDE] IntelliJ, Netbeans, Code Blocks
\item[Text Editor] Vim, VSCode
\item[OS] Ubuntu, Fedora, Kali Linux, Windows
\item[Typesetting] \LaTeX{}, Open office, Microsoft office
\end{CV}
\section{References}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
  \textbf{Dr. Md. Mustafizur Rahman}\\
  Professor \& Chairperson\\
Computer Science \& Engineering\\
University of Dhaka\\
\faPhone{} +8801927199301(Cell)\\
\faPhone (880)-2-9661900 Ext. 7433 (Office)\\
\faEnvelopeO{} \href{mailto:mustafiz@du.ac.bd}{mustafiz@du.ac.bd}\\
\faEnvelopeO{} \href{mailto:mustafiz1952@gmail.com}{mustafiz1952@gmail.com}\\
\faEnvelopeO{} \href{mailto:mustafiz1952@yahoo.com}{mustafiz1952@yahoo.com}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\noindent \today



\end{document}

%Tabellen
\begin{table}[htbp] \centering%
\begin{tabular}{lll}\hline\hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
1 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Titel\label{Tabelle: Label}}
\end{table}
```

[image]

I want to add a image in right add Name to left(existing box of name to left new box).

Comment: `\Large{text}` is wrong, it should be `{\Large text}`

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193555/crop-jpeg-into-circular-tikz-node or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154882/how-to-clip-an-external-image-inside-an-ellipse

Comment: You have been told multiple times that the syntax is wrong, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451112/general-guideline-for-setting-appropriate-font-size-for-a-document#comment1134033_451112 Why don't you change it?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fullpage,graphicx,tikz}

%\usepackage{doublespace}
%\setstretch{1.2}

%\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage{CV}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
      linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

%Ueberschrift
\begin{center}
\huge{\textsc{Curriculum Vitae}}
\vspace{\baselineskip}

\end{center}
\vspace{1.5\baselineskip}
\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
\Large{\textsc{MD.Al-Helal}}\\
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip(0,0)circle[radius=1.37cm,];
    \node{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{Image/myPhoto.jpg}};   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\section{Address}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{.7\textwidth}
  Room no-1406\\
  Shahid Sarafat Ali Building\\
  Dr. Muhammad Shahidullah Hall\\
  University of Dhaka\\
  Dhaka-1000\\
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.7\textwidth}
  \faPhone{} +8801515-611989\\
  \faEnvelopeO{}  \href{mailto:al2helal@gmail.com}{al2helal@gmail.com}\\
  \faEnvelopeO{}  \href{mailto:alhelal@ieee.org}{alhelal@ieee.org}\\
  \faGithub{}  \href{https://github.com/al2helal}{al2helal}\\
  \faLinkedin{}  \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/mdalhelal/}{al2helal}\\
  \faStackOverflow{}  \href{https://stackoverflow.com/users/5697418/alhelal}{alhelal}
\end{minipage}

\section{Career Objective}
\begin{CV}
\item Solving real life problem those suffers humanity and making effective products for society by hard working and responsibility. And thereby build up an efficient career in the computer science and engineering and serve humanity.
  \end{CV}

\section{Project Experience}

\begin{CV}

\item[2018] Completed a project on making a e-commerce site(an online handicraft's store). I used PHP in back-end(server) and HTML, CSS, JavaScript, AJAX in front-end. I also used MySql in this project to build a MariaDB database.
\item[2017] Completed a project on making a suggestion provider text editor with IDE features. In this editor, user can edit and compile different programming languages's source code. The editor has a intelegence module that can help the user providing stackoverflow suggestion on his/her error of code.
%\item[2017] Completed a project on building a statistical predictive and recommendation model on universtity student's salary as tutor. I used R to complete this project.
\end{CV}


\section{Education}

\begin{CV}
\item[2015--current] University of Dhaka, Dhaka-1000.\\Continued  B.S in Computer Science \& Engineering. Currently in 4\textsuperscript{th} year.\\Obtained CGPA 3.33 (upto 3rd year)
\item[2014] Carmichael College, Rangpur.\\Passed H.S.C (Science Group) under Dinajpur Board in 2014.\\Obtained GPA 5.00 (without 4\textsuperscript{th} subject score) out of 5.00.
\item[2012] Moyenpur High School, Mithapukur, Rangpur.\\Passed S.S.C (Science Group) under Dinajpur Board in 2012.\\Obtained GPA 5.00 (without 4\textsuperscript{th} subject score) out of 5.00.
\end{CV}


%\section{Language Skills}
%\begin{table}[h] %\centering
%\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}>{}p{2.5cm}p{3cm}}
%Bangali  & native \\
%English  & 2nd language\\
%\end{tabular}
%\end{table}


%\section{Areas of Interest}
%\begin{CV}
%\item Machine learning, System programming, Making helpful shell script.
%\end{CV}


\section{Scholarship}

\begin{CV}
\item[2009] Obtained National Education Board Scholarship for good result in class 8.
\item[2014] Obtained National Education Board Scholarship for good result in H.S.C under Dinajpur Board.
\end{CV}

%\section{Technical Skills}
%\begin{table}[h]
%  \begin{tabular}{p{5cm}>{}p{6cm}}
%    Programming Languages  & C, Java, Sql, Mysql, HTML, R, Assembly\\
%    Tools & Oracle database, PhpMyadmin\\
%Version Control  & Git\\
%IDE & IntelliJ, Netbeans, Code Blocks\\
%Text Editor & Vim\\
%Operating System & Ubuntu, Fedora, Windows\\
%Typesetting & \LaTeX{}, Open office, Microsoft office\\
%\end{tabular}
%\end{table}

\section{Technical Skills}

\begin{CV}
\item[Languages]  Java, PHP, Python, C, Sql, Mysql, HTML, R, Assembly
\item[Tools] Oracle database, PhpMyadmin
\item[VCS] Git
\item[IDE] IntelliJ, Netbeans, Code Blocks
\item[Text Editor] Vim, VSCode
\item[OS] Ubuntu, Fedora, Kali Linux, Windows
\item[Typesetting] \LaTeX{}, Open office, Microsoft office
\end{CV}
\section{References}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
  \textbf{Dr. Md. Mustafizur Rahman}\\
  Professor \& Chairperson\\
Computer Science \& Engineering\\
University of Dhaka\\
\faPhone{} +8801927199301(Cell)\\
\faPhone (880)-2-9661900 Ext. 7433 (Office)\\
\faEnvelopeO{} \href{mailto:mustafiz@du.ac.bd}{mustafiz@du.ac.bd}\\
\faEnvelopeO{} \href{mailto:mustafiz1952@gmail.com}{mustafiz1952@gmail.com}\\
\faEnvelopeO{} \href{mailto:mustafiz1952@yahoo.com}{mustafiz1952@yahoo.com}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\noindent \today



\end{document}

%Tabellen
\begin{table}[htbp] \centering%
\begin{tabular}{lll}\hline\hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
1 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Titel\label{Tabelle: Label}}
\end{table}
```

[image]